# If $\int^1_0 |f_n(t)-f(t)|dt\, \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$ then does $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^1_0 f_n(t) dt\,=\int^1_0 f(t)dt\,$

Tags: real-analysis

> Let $\{f_n\}$be sequence of bounded real valued functions on $[0,1]$ converging at all points of this interval. Then 
>   If $\int^1_0 |f_n(t)-f(t)|dt\, \to 0$ as $n \to \infty$,does $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int^1_0 f_n(t) dt\,=\int^1_0 f(t)dt\,$

I just know that if somehow we can show uniform convergence then we can say it would be true, but in other case what happens I don't know!

Answer (score 3):

$$\left|\int^1_0 f_n(t)\,\mathrm dt-\int^1_0 f(t)\,\mathrm dt\right|\leqslant\int^1_0 \left|f_n(t) - f(t)\right|\,\mathrm dt$$

Comment: I suppose $f_n$ and $f$ are all continuous and we don't have the condition $\int^1_0 |f_n(t)-f(t)|dt\, \to 0$ as $n\to \infty$, then  does $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int^1_0 f_n(t)dt\,=\int^1_0 f(t)dt\,$?

Comment: Sorry but I have no idea what your comment is about. That the RHS $\to0$ is a hypothesis, no?

Comment: I'm asking does $\lim_{n\to \infty}\int^1_0 f_n(t)dt\,=\int^1_0 f(t)dt\,$ still holds if we're not given that $\int^1_0 |f_n(t)-f(t)|dt\, \to 0$ , but we are given that $f_n$ and $f$ are continuous!

Comment: Wow--it is nearly impossible to guess that THIS is your question by reading your post. At least to me. (And the answer to the question in your comment is obviously no.)

Comment: oh sorry for that !

Answer (score 0):

This result is false. Let $f_{n}$ be zero for $x\leq\tfrac{1}{n+1}$ and $0$ for $x\geq \tfrac{1}{n}$. Then connect both points $(\tfrac{1}{n+1},0)$ and $(\tfrac{1}{n},0)$ to $(\tfrac{1}{2n}+\tfrac{1}{2n+1},n(n+1))$, Notice what the integral for each $f_{n}$ is and see what it converges to.